# Why has my slave server stopped connecting to master in MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, ssl

We have MySQL replication setup and it has been running without issue for some time. This server acts as a slave and a master (it replicates through to another server). This morning I received an alert to say it has stopped:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 123.456.78.90
                  Master_User: replication
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: binary-log.000006
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 225898044
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000018
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: binary-log.000006
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: mysql.%
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 225898044
              Relay_Log_Space: 107
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
           Master_SSL_CA_File: /var/lib/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert: /var/lib/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key: /var/lib/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2026
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replication@134.213.65.178:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified
```

If I try connect from the same machine:

[user@host~]# mysql -u replication -p -h 123.456.78.90
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 35069260
...

And permissions from the master:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replication@123.456.78.90                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replication'@'123.456.78.90' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*E2F700F7365XXXXXXXXXX9F3A4C5C17C' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The error log on the slave shows:

```
150709 20:59:00 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'replication@123.456.78.90:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2026
```

It was at that point I remembered last night updates were run:

```
Updating:
 mysql55w         x86_64    5.5.44-1.w6
 mysql55w-libs    x86_64    5.5.44-1.w6
 mysql55w-server  x86_64    5.5.44-1.w6
```

But I've not been able to find any related information to this particular update. The error, `2026`, is the following:

```
Error: 2026 (CR_SSL_CONNECTION_ERROR)
Message: SSL connection error: %s
```

The certificates haven't changed and the paths are specified correctly on the slave as show at the start of the question. I found if I run:

```
[user@host ~]# mysql --ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem -u replication -p -h 123.456.78.90
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

So it appears that, for some reason, the SSL certificates have suddenly stopped working, though they haven't changed for months on both the master and slave.

**Where should I turn next to figure out the problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could be because of openssl update.
take a look at the following

https://github.com/iuscommunity-pkg/mysql55/issues/4

> a notable bug that occurs with
>   the latest version of OpenSSL. This issue prevents secure connections from being
>   made due to the default hardcoded cipher no longer being supported in the  newer
>   version of OpenSSL. Below is an example of the error:

```
[root@server newrscerts2]$ mysql -u rs -p'lamepassword' \
                            --ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/newrscerts/ca.pem --ssl
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

> You can work around this issue by specifying a different cipher manually.

```
[root@server ~]$ mysql -u rs -p'lamepassword' \
                  --ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/newrscerts2/ca-cert.pem \
                  --ssl-cipher=AES128-SHA

Welcome to the MySQL monitor. 
Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10057
Server version: 5.5.43-log Distributed by The IUS Community Project
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

> Further details can be found at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1228755.

Comment: Great, on the command line I can connect using  `--ssl-cipher=AES128-SHA`, but how would I set this up for replication?

Comment: you should do the following:
`mysql> stop slave;
mysql> change master to  master_ssl=1, master_ssl_ca='/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem', master_ssl_cert='/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem', master_ssl_key='/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem', master_ssl_cipher='AES128-SHA';
mysql> start slave;`
and it will start replicating again

Comment: Will that keep the correct values in the binlog settings?

Comment: yes it just modifies the ssl params, it doesn't change anything in binlog.

Comment: Options not specified retain their value, except as indicated in the following discussion. Thus, in most cases, there is no need to specify options that do not change.
[mysqlDocumentaion link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/change-master-to.html)

Comment: I ended up just doing `CHANGE MASTER TO master_ssl=1, master_ssl_cipher='AES128-SHA';` but essentially what you recommended - many thanks!