# MySQL 5.5 replication over SSL broken after upgrading OpenSSL, OS

Tags: mysql, replication, ssl

I've got an issue where, after upgrading a replication slave from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, this slave can no longer connect to its master using SSL.

**Setup before the upgrade:**

1 master, 2 slaves, ALL running mysql-5.5 (client and server).  All on Ubuntu 14.04, with OpenSSL 1.0.1f.

**Setup now:**

One change was made: I upgraded one of the slaves to Ubuntu 16.04.  I kept the mysql version on that server at 5.5.  However, OpenSSL did get upgraded to OpenSSL 1.0.2g.

Since the upgrade, this replication slave can no longer connect to its master via SSL.  The error received is:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

I feel confident that this is an SSL issue, because I am able to connect to the master **without** using SSL (both from the commandline and via the slave threads).

I have tried disabling DH key exchange (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1228755) and specifying a different cypher ([Why has my slave server stopped connecting to master in MySQL replication?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106562/why-has-my-slave-server-stopped-connecting-to-master-in-mysql-replication)), but none of that seems to help.  I continue to get the 2026 error that I mentioned above.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: is there anything in the master/slave mysql error log?

Comment: which replication SSL options are you using? What is the certificate type and the key size for the public key? What type of public key?